# How to parse HAR file to extract text content?

Tags: python, har

I saved my network data in a har file. Now I want to extract the whole dictionary of content that contains specific word as an indicator to save that dictionary to an array. There are multiple similar dicts in the har file that contain that value and I want to create an array of all the responses.

I am fairly new to python(and coding in general), explainlikeimfive kind explanation will greatly help me.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/haralyzer/ looks like it may be a good fit.  It can parse and analyze a har file.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`haralyzer`](https://pypi.org/project/haralyzer/) module. You can install it easily using `pip` like so:

```
pip install haralyzer
```

The following code uses this sample [har file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cijWmVUgOLlFRgLsKvmEAOLhg6BFvn7_/view?usp=sharing):

```
>>> import json
>>> from haralyzer import HarParser, HarPage
>>>
>>> with open('sample.har', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     har_parser = HarParser(json.loads(f.read()))
>>>
>>> data = har_parser.har_data
>>> type(data)
<class 'dict'>
>>>
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['version', 'creator', 'pages', 'entries'])
>>>
>>> har_parser.har_data["pages"]
[{'startedDateTime': '2013-08-24T20:16:16.997Z', 'id': 'page_1', 'title': 'http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/', 'pageTimings': {'onContentLoad': 317, 'onLoad': 406}}]
```

For more info, check the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/mrname/haralyzer).

Comment: How can I access specific responses (text that the site was showing to the user) that contain a word? The har file is huge around 200 mb. To clarify the data is shown as a table in the site. So there are multiple table like data in form of dict in the har file

Comment: could you provide this har file?

Comment: How can i provide you the har? It contains alot of data that Im not sure if I can share

Comment: Then, you can use my code as a starting point and if you found any problem with it, I'm happy to help

Comment: I have created a smaller har and changed as much as I could to make it okay
How can I send it to you?

Comment: upload it to a cloud service like GoogleDrive and provide the link in the question.

Comment: Hi Anwarvic, would you mind checking your linked in?

Comment: Heads up people. The "har file" link is not a link but a download. Be careful!

Comment: @X_Trust, I have changed the link. Now, you can view the file before downloading.

Comment: haralyzer seems to be broken. Unable to read har files with it

Comment: @Alex same problem here. Structure issues, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Tacking on to the answer from Anwarvic, entries in the HAR file that have a text-based content type contain the actual content in the key `entry -> response -> content -> text`. So, here is an example printing the content of all such entries.

```
.... initialize har parser as per documentation ....

for page in har_parser.pages:
    for entry in page.entries:
        # Need to be careful accessing the text property, it will not exist for non text-based responses.
        print(entry['response']['content'].get('text', ''))
```

From there you can use `in` or a regex to see if the response text of the entry matches the text you are looking for.